# Cannot read property 'Documento' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to query an object that is stored on my firestore database and to do so i am using a json format to iterate through the object and display it on HTML. 
At first, i was able to display on my console log, but after refreshing my page i started getting the errors on my google chrome developer console.

Here's how i am trying it

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    var auxint = 0;
    this.dataAux
    let auxString = '[';
    db.collection('Usuario').where("Deletado", "==", false).get().then(res => {
      res.forEach(item => {

        //pegue todos os dados do banco e crie um novo JSON com as informações de 
        auxint++;
        auxString += '{"id":"' + item.id + '","documento":' + JSON.stringify(item.data()) + '}';

        if (res.size != auxint)
          auxString += ', ';
      })
      auxString += ']';
      this.dataJSON = JSON.parse(auxString);

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('algum erro ' + err);
    });
  }
```

Where Usuario is my collection name.

my .html file

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let data of dataJSON">
  <ion-item>
    <h3>DataCriacao: {{data.DataCriacao}}</h3>
    <p>DataUpdate: {{data.DataUpdate}}</p>
    <p>DELETADO: {{data.Deletado}}</p>
    <p>EMAIL: {{data.Usuario.Documento.email}}</p>
    <p>ID: {{data.Usuario.Documento.id}}</p>
    <p>NOME: {{data.Usuario.Documento.nome}}</p>
    <p>SENHA: {{data.Usuario.Documento.senha}}</p>
    <p>TELEFONE: {{data.Usuario.Documento.telefone}}</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
```

data is my iteration data, Usuario is my collection and Documento is my object stored inside firestore, everything else are just field values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDaXV.jpg

Comment: I don't think you're referencing your data correctly. You've created an array of objects with "id" and "documento", where "documento" contains the data, but you're referencing things like "Usuario", which don't exist on the objects. Maybe something like, ```data.documento.Documento``` would give you a better result?

Comment: thats a very nice observation, im using Usuario not documento, managed to fix it! kudos buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this error by using **`*ngIf`** OR **`safe navigation operator (?)`** .

**`Reason`**: It's just a console error that occurs when you try to access the dataJSON in the template before the actual value is set on the component. this happens because the data is assigned asynchronously.

Solution:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let data of dataJSON">
  <ion-item>
    <h3>DataCriacao: {{data?.DataCriacao}}</h3>
    <p>DataUpdate: {{data?.DataUpdate}}</p>
    <p>DELETADO: {{data?.Deletado}}</p>
    <p>EMAIL: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.email}}</p>
    <p>ID: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.id}}</p>
    <p>NOME: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.nome}}</p>
    <p>SENHA: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.senha}}</p>
    <p>TELEFONE: {{data?.Usuario?.Documento?.telefone}}</p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
```

Comment: It successfully removed all errors, only thing is that its not displaying my data: https://imgur.com/a/CQ6vkNQ

Comment: you dont have to parse data , it should be a JSON   this.dataJSON = auxString;

Comment: Saved my day again dude!

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach would be to check if `data` exists or not instead of using so many `safe( ? )` operators. Something like this:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let data of dataJSON">
  <ion-item *ngIf="data">
    <h3>DataCriacao: {{data.DataCriacao}}</h3>
    <p>DataUpdate: {{data.DataUpdate}}</p>
    <p>DELETADO: {{data.Deletado}}</p>
    <p>EMAIL: {{data.Usuario.Documento.email}}</p>
    <p>ID: {{data.Usuario.Documento.id}}</p>
    <p>NOME: {{data.Usuario.Documento.nome}}</p>
    <p>SENHA: {{data.Usuario.Documento.senha}}</p>
    <p>TELEFONE: {{data.Usuario.Documento.telefone}}</p>
  </ion-item>
<ion-item-options>
```

Also, in your TypeScript class, you could use Template Strings Syntax:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  let db = firebase.firestore();
  var auxint = 0;
  this.dataAux
  let auxString = '[';
  db.collection('Usuario').where("Deletado", "==", false).get().then(res => {
    res.forEach(item => {

      //pegue todos os dados do banco e crie um novo JSON com as informações de 
      auxint++;
      auxString += `{"id":"${item.id}","documento":${JSON.stringify(item.data())}}`;

      if (res.size != auxint)
        auxString += ', ';
    })
    auxString += ']';
    this.dataJSON = JSON.parse(auxString);

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('algum erro ' + err);
  });
}
```

Comment: even if data exists nested object will fail and i have actually mentioned in the answer .